# JSON parsing "NULL"

Tags: json, delphi

I have this code working until today. If there is for egxample this:

> "status":null

there will be exception "Invalid class type". How to fix it? Thanks for help.

```
procedure TForm1.Button10Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  IdHTTP: TIdHTTP;
  IdSSL: TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL;
  JSON: string;
  jsonObiekt: TJSONObject;
  streams: TJSONArray;
  stream: TJSONObject;
  channel: TJSONObject;
  status: TJSONString;
  liczbaStrumieni: integer;
  i: integer;
begin
  IdHTTP := TIdHTTP.Create;
  try
    IdSSL := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(IdHTTP);
    IdHTTP.IOHandler := IdSSL;
    IdHTTP.Request.Accept := 'application/vnd.twitchtv.v3+json';
    IdHTTP.Request.CustomHeaders.AddValue('Client-ID', 'smb61nyd0vxmqdn9d3k735qbx41cdyg');
    JSON := IdHTTP.Get('https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams?game=StarCraft:%20Brood%20War');
  finally
    IdHTTP.Free;
  end;
  jsonObiekt := TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue(JSON) as TJSONObject;
  try
    streams := jsonObiekt.Get('streams').JsonValue as TJSONArray;
    liczbaStrumieni := streams.Size;
    for i := 0 to liczbaStrumieni - 1 do
    begin
      stream := streams.Get(i) as TJSONObject;
      channel := stream.Get('channel').JsonValue as TJSONObject;
      status := channel.Get('status').JsonValue as TJSONString;
      Memo6.Lines.Add(status.Value);
    end;
  finally
    jsonObiekt.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: The whole point of the `as` operator is to throw an exception if the object being cast is not of the correct type, so of course `as TJSONObject` throws an exception when `ParseJSONValue` returns something which is not a `TJSONObject`. What did you expect would happen?

Comment: @hvd `null` is a valid JSON value. See http://json.org/

Comment: @Barmar I know it is a valid value, but in Delphi, `TJSONNull` derives from `TJSONValue`, not from `TJSONObject`, so `ParseJSONValue` is returning something which is not a `TJSONObject`, just like I stated in my comment.

Comment: I think he just needs to use something like `if(channel.Get('status').JsonValue is TJSONString) ...`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I see from the comments that you're familiar with the JSON specification on JSON.org.  Your problem appears to be with understanding how it maps to the DBXJSON model.

Specifically, `TJSONObject` represents **an Object as defined by the JSON standard.**  It does *not* mean "a (Delphi) object that holds JSON data."  That's what `TJSONValue` is there for.  Try using that instead.